# Using Neo4j with Java by Passing Cypher Query into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, neo4j

I'm working with neo4j-community-3.4.7 and Eclipse Oxygen. I've installed the neo4j driver and added  the neo4j community edition lib files to my Eclipse library. My problem is that I'm trying to import a csv file located in the import folder of the neo4j-community directory by passing in the Cypher query through a transaction. Passing other Cypher queries this way has been successful in creating nodes and relationships in the database. However, when I try to use "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" to load a large csv I get an error message saying "cannot use periodic commit on a non-updating query."

I've attached my code with the other lines of the transaction commented out, which should work once the csv file is successfully loaded.

[image]

Comment: That error would be expected with the current form of your query, with most of it commented out and just returning the line. When you use periodic commit you must perform updates, so just a return without any modification to the graph would trigger that error. What happens if you use the full query instead?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image. Code in images cannot be copy/pasted, making it hard for others to reproduce your problem and try to solve it.